# ViewPager & tabs: Delay after clicking tab

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

i wrote a FragmentActivity with a ViewPager, i did not want to use the actionbar for the tabs (because i did not want the tabs to be positioned over the menu) and also not the PagerTabStrip solution, because i could not customize it as i wanted.

so i wrote an own linearlayout as tabs container:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

with an View.OnClickListener for each of each tab

```
OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            mapTabs.get(lastSelectedTab).setSelected(false);
            view.setSelected(true);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {                    
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
                    FragmentActivity.setTab(index);
                    lastSelectedTab = index;
                }
            };
            handler.post(runnable);                 
        }
    };
}



public static void setTab(int index) {      
    FragmentActivity.viewPager.setCurrentItem(index, true); // true or false does not make any difference
}
```

this is the method i wrote to add the single tabs to the tab container (main_tabs):

```
private void addTab(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup tabs, int imageId, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_tab, tabs);
    int index = tabs.getChildCount() - 1;
    ImageView ivTab = (ImageView) tabs.getChildAt(index);
    ivTab.setTag(String.valueOf(index)); // stored the tab index
    ivTab.setImageResource(imageId); 
    ivTab.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    mapTabs.put(index, ivTab); // add an imageview to the tab
}
```

i used the runnalbe so that i see the highlighting of the tab immediately, and not after the slight delay when the new page appears. i also stored the last selected tab in order to deselect it when the new one gets selected.

i store all tabs in a map in order to access them later for selection.

this is the OnPageChangeListener i wrote (to highlight the associated tab):

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {              
            mapTabs.get(position).setSelected(true); // selected the tag asociated with the current visible page
            mapTabs.get(lastSelectedTab).setSelected(false); // deselectes the last selected tab
            lastSelectedTab = position;
            ListFragment<?> item = FragmentActivity.fragmentAdapter.getItem(position);
            setTitle(item.getTitle());          
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

everything works fine, i am just not clear about the performance:

when i scroll to the next page, everything goes very fast and smooth. the next page appears immediately without any dealy; only the menu in the action bar (created in the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) method of each Fragment) appears with a slight delay (about 500-700 ms).

but when i click on one of the tabs, the selected page appears not immediately but with a slight delay (actually the same time the menu needs to appear as mentioned above: menu and page appear together at the same time). bzw. this happens also when i use the tabstrip solution.

i guess if its possible to achieve a delay-less page change by scrolling, it should be possible somehow to achieve the same performance for the tab clicks.

but what do i do wrong?
and is there a possibility to make the menu appear immediately just like the pages when scrolling? can the different menus not be cached just like the pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the solution was extremely simple. i just had to keep all my 4 tabs in the ViewPager so that they don't need to get recreated (and therefore don't cause the short delay after each tab-clicki). i just had to add following lines to the onCreate method.

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid delay  between tabs click in view pager should set the limit of tabs like

pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
myViewPager.animate().translationX(0f).setDuration(1000);
```

where 1000 is delay in milliseconds

Comment: thanks for the information. i tried it but it did not help. even the time of 5000 for test reasons did not change anything. anyway sometimes it changes smoothly sometimes is kind of gets reloaded (also sometimes the method onActivityCreated for the pages gets called, and sometimes not).

Comment: now i put your line to the onClick method and variated it this way:

viewPager.animate().translationX(index * iPageWidth * -1).setDuration(1000);

but it moved the complete page with all its tabs and did not scoll the single page

Comment: the smoothness of animation differs on emulator, check on real device.and implement viewPager.animate().translateX(0f).setDuration(1000); in onPageChangeListner method and make viewPager as final.

Comment: i used a real device. maybe i missunderstood something but the problem does not seem to be in the OnPageChangeListener because everything is fine when scrolling the page (the associated tabs get selected as they should). the problem located in the OnClickListener for the tabs that calls viewPager.setCurrentItem(index), and thats where i added your code but had the results described in my last post.

Comment: ok i got this, in your first comment the page reloaded again because viewPager is called twice. Once at setCurrentItemIndex(Index) and again at  myViewPager.animate().translationX(0f).setDuration(1000); try myViewPager.animate().translationX(0f).setDuration(1000).setCurrentItemIndex(Index);

Comment: i also tried just calling the translation method but it did not help. anyway the method setDuration(1000) returns a ViewPropertyAnimator. i can not call the method setCurrentItem(index) on it.